# Django-tinymce not showing in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-tinymce

I installed django-tinymce, put it in the installed apps, added the url. Then I created a model as below:

```
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

class Post(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
```

I have also registered this model into the admin. When trying to add a `Post` instance through the admin, all the fields are showing, except for the `content` field. That is the field using Tinymce. The field is just white space with no option to input anything. Anybody know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
from tinymce import HTMLField

class Post(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = HTMLField()
```

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLField' from 'tinymce' (E:\full-stack projects\django-boilerplate\env\lib\site-packages\tinymce\__init__.py)`